# KeyBy multiple streams in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have multiple (3 to be precise as of now) streams (of different types) from different kafka topics. They have a common property `userId`. All I want to do now is to partition by userId and then add some business logic to it. How can I partition by userId all streams and ensure that all the events go to the same task processor so that userId state is accessible ?
I could have used ConnectedStream but here the usecase is for more than 2 different kind of streams.

Also I was wondering weather something like this would guarantee same task processor

```
MyBusinessProcess businessProcess() = new MyBusinessProcess();
streamA.keyBy(event -> event.userId).process(businessProcess);
streamB.keyBy(event -> event.userId).process(businessProcess);
streamC.keyBy(event -> event.userId).process(businessProcess);
```

Edit: I just realised that for businessProcess, how would it differentiate between which event is coming in if there are stream of multiple types. Gets me thinking more since this seems like a naive streams problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a class (let's call it `Either3`) that has a userID field, and then three additional fields (only one of which is ever set) that contain your three different stream's data type (look at Flink's `Either` class for how to do this for 2 values).

Then use a map function on each of your three streams to convert from class A/B/C to an `Either3` with the appropriate value set.

Now you can `.union()` your three streams together, and run that one stream into your business process function, which can maintain state as needed.

Comment: Thanks @kkrugler Yes that's how I kind of solved it right now, by using Tuple3. But I am still thinking whether there's a generic solution to this problem. What if I have four streams in the next usecase?

Comment: Probably I will need a unified view to represent my events to make things simpler!!

Comment: FWIW, internally Flink does have an n-ary operator, but it's only used for SQL joins, and isn't exposed through the DataStream API. If you can express your business logic in SQL, that would be an alternative.